# mod-rewrite rule works, but no output from file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

thanks in advance, this is an odd problem, but probably is some internal processing I don't understand...
The rules and conditions work as expected except for one tiny problem.... it seems to be returning an empty file when the file is not empty...
On the bright side I got logging working, and am starting to have a clue about the very cryptic codes (thank you mr. apache and of course apache.org, and for those who want to test there regex: regex101.com)
Here is my log file:

```
[Sat Dec 06 19:04:49.939312 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5918] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.100:55227] 192.168.1.100 - - [webtypography.dev/sid#7fdcea80dd68][rid#7fdcea7de0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/webtypography.dev/public_html/] pass through /var/www/webtypography.dev/public_html/toc.php
```

this is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webtypography\.dev$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)\/$  $1.php [R=301,L]
```

A little more info: My intent is if you type in the url which includes a directory: `/directory/` it is rewritten as `directory.php` and appended to the base url....works great except the big blank browser viewport...

```
[Sat Dec 06 19:04:49.939265 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5918] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.100:55227] 192.168.1.100 - - [webtypography.dev/sid#7fdcea80dd68][rid#7fdcea7de0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/webtypography.dev/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/webtypography.dev/public_html/toc.php -> toc.php
[Sat Dec 06 19:04:49.939301 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5918] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.100:55227] 192.168.1.100 - - [webtypography.dev/sid#7fdcea80dd68][rid#7fdcea7de0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/webtypography.dev/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)\\/$' to uri 'toc.php'
[Sat Dec 06 19:04:49.939312 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5918] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.100:55227] 192.168.1.100 - - [webtypography.dev/sid#7fdcea80dd68][rid#7fdcea7de0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/webtypography.dev/public_html/] pass through /var/www/webtypography.dev/public_html/toc.php
```

These are the only entries in my virtual log for that transaction (i created a separate log for this virtual host...) Also this is NOT a production server, but I am going to look at php.ini and the php error log.... I'm not allowed to comment so I must do this here?

php.ini is display_errors was off!
Now I got the errors I need... THANKS NIEL! Allow me to check these errors, they are simple to fix, how can I give you any credit for this?

Comment: Empty output is 99.999999% of the time caused by a PHP or Apache error, with `display_errors=no` as you should on production. Check your Apache errors logs for the vhost.

Comment: 99.999999% of the credit goes to Niels, I still have to fix this... :)

Comment: It wasn't the vhosts Niels... I had that on already, it was your direction towards php.ini, and on a side note, finding php.ini is easy if you just view a php page with php_info()

Comment: Please remember to disable `display_errors` after debugging, it's a ***MAJOR*** security hole to leave it on.

Comment: Excellent work Niels thank you I've been on this site briefly and I've seen your wealth of knowledge displayed in other posts... Being unexperienced as I am, the server was by default configured with display_errors=no as it should be for people like me incase I had been working on a production server!

Comment: Please stop trying to edit my answer to respond to it - if you want to add something to it use a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PHP or Apache produces empty output this is nearly always caused by an error in either your Apache configs, including `.htaccess` files, or in your PHP with `display_errors` being disabled (as it damn well should be on a production site - you never want to show server internals to a possible attacker).

First stop should be Apache's vhost error logs as they will contain the errors from all these sources.